# Check if msg.sender is a specific type of contract

Tags: solidity, contract-design

Is it possible to check if `msg.sender` is a contract of a specific type?

For example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;
contract Baz {

    function Baz(){
        // want this to fail
        new Foo();
    }
}

contract Bar {

    function Bar(){
        new Foo();
    }
}

contract Foo {
    Bar bar;


    function Foo(){
        // how to make sure that msg.sender is of type Bar?
        bar = Bar(msg.sender);
    }
}
```

I've tried this in Remix and running it `Baz` in remix doesn't cause any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this short and simple. It would guard against accidental mix-ups, but not deliberate impersonation.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;
contract Baz {

    function Baz(){
        // want this to fail
        new Foo();
    }
}

contract Bar {

    function Bar(){
        new Foo();
    }

    function iAmBar() public pure returns(bool isIndeed) {
        return true;
    }
}

contract Foo {
    Bar bar;


    function Foo(){
        // how to make sure that msg.sender is of type Bar?
        bar = Bar(msg.sender);
        require(bar.iAmBar());
    }
}
```

Another way to go is to whitelist all the "friendly" contracts. In the case you have more than one deployer, you would use a separate whitelist to catalogue all the "friendlies". A simpler example just has your `Bar` contract keep track of its progeny.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;
contract Baz {

    function Baz(){
        // want this to fail
        new Foo();
    }
}

contract Bar {

    mapping(address => bool) public isWhiteListed;

    function Bar(){
        Foo f = new Foo();
        isWhiteListed[address(f)] = true;
    }

}

contract Foo {
    Bar bar;


    function Foo(){
        // how to make sure that msg.sender is of type Bar?
        bar = Bar(msg.sender);
        require(bar.isWhiteListed(address(bar)));
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can't `iAmBar` and `isWhiteListed` be impersonated? For example, can't `Baz` implement an `iAmBar` method which always returns true?

Comment: Yes. I think you'll be stuck when trying to restrict a constructor this way. By definition, anyone who is deploying has the source and can even modify it as needed. If you flip it around and say something like `Bar` has functions that are restricted to known `Foo` then the rules and structure will be easier to sort out.